# Question: How do I render a plot once an 'action button' is clicked in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm referencing [Update Plot output on ActionButton click event in R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242792/update-plot-output-on-actionbutton-click-event-in-r-shiny) for an attempt at a solution, but I am not yet successful.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    
runtime: shiny
---
    
```{r setup, include=FALSE}


library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

```


## Column {.sidebar}


<hr>


```{r}
  

shiny::actionButton(
    inputId = "button_1",
    label   = "Click Me",
  
)


```



Column {data-width=650} 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot 

```{r}

 
 v <- reactiveValues(data = mtcars,
                     plot = NULL
                         )

  observeEvent(input$button_1, {
   
      data <- mtcars
      
      v$plot <- ggplot(v$data, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
                geom_line(color = "blue") 
    
     
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
     
    if (is.null(v$plot)) return()
    v$plot
  
    })

```
````

Comment: Are you trying to make the plot invisible until the button is pressed?

Comment: Hi Kat,  Either way is fine.  My preference is to have an initial line plot rendered and then replaced with an additional line once the button is pressed. If that is a pain, I can leave it blank until the button is pressed.